# Interpretation of Time Domain simulation output

Tags: pspice, orcad

I have the following circuit and I want to know the voltage on each node and the current on each loop. I've run the Time Domain simulation (I'm not sure of the differences between this and Bias Point simulation) and I've got the following results:

[image]

However, I'm not sure about what figure points to what nodes and loops. Can you give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: what time duration spec-line did you use? Show that line of the .CIR file.

Comment: You can read the currents in the three loops at R1, R3, R5. Mind their direction! The currents at R2 and R4 are sum currents.

Comment: *I'm not sure of the differences between this and Bias Point simulation* A time domain simulation simulates **over time**, like the charging of a capacitor. There are no capacitors (or inductors) in your circuit so it is pointless to simulate over time. A Bias point simulation simulates the "steady state" of the circuit, since your circuit has no time dependent components (caps, inductors) the result of time sim. and Bias point will be **the same**.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a maths and circuit theory question, not a pspice simulation question.

You could use a simulation to check your work, but that's not usually the correct answer as it's only valid for one set of values.

You can use circuit theory such as Norton and Thevenin equivilance and superposition to simplify the circuit, but this is simple enough to just solve it as a system of simultanious equations.

As this looks like an exam question I will not provide a complete answer, but I'll show the process to solve it.

**1: Identify loops, in this case there are three A, B and C**

 - A is V1(15V), R1 and R2
 - B is R2, R3 and R4
 - C is R4, R5 and V2(5V)

**2: Identify current summation and define current conventions**

 - In my world currents flow clockwise in loops
 - Currents generate a voltage in the opposite direction in resistors
 - Sources generate currents in the same direction
 - Currents in the circuit flow left to right in the top line
 - and flow top to bottom in the verticals

i1 flows in R1
i2 flows in R3
i3 flows in R5

This picture shows the process

[image]

**3: Write voltage equations for each loop**

If the wire current (black arrows) direction match the loop direction (red arrows) it's positive, otherwise it's negative.
If the loop and wire are in the same direction then draw the voltage arrow (blue) one way, if they differ it's the other way round.
It does not matter what conventions you use so long as you are consistent.

Then just write out what you see, like this:
Loop A:
$$
V1 = i1*R1 + (i1 - i2) * R2
$$
Loop B:
$$
0 = i2*R3 + (i2-i3)*R4 - (i1-i2)*R2
$$
Loop C:
$$
-V2 = i3*R5 - (i2-i3)*R4
$$

We now have three equations and three unknowns so we can solve it (the answer is given but the working is left to the reader).

**4: Solve the system of equations to find the unknown currents**

$${i1} = $$$${{(R2*(R5+R4)+R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)*V1-R2*R4*V2} \over {R2*(R1*(R5+R4)+R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)+R1*(R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)}}
$$

$${i2} = $$$${{-R4*V2*(R2+R1)+R2*(R5+R4)*V1} \over {R2*(R1*(R5+R4)+R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)+R1*(R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)}}
$$

$$i3 = $$$${{-V2*(R2*(R4+R3+R1)+R1*(R4+R3))+R2*R4*V1} \over {R2*(R1*(R5+R4)+R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)+R1*(R4*(R5+R3)+R3*R5)}}
$$

Now you can plug known values in (all the R's and V's) to get the currents (i's) in any component, e.g.
Voltage across R2 is $$V(R2) = (i1-i2)*R2$$

You can use programs such as [sMath](https://en.smath.com/view/SMathStudio/summary), [Mathcad](https://www.ptc.com/en/products/mathcad) and [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) to help you with more complicated systems. The process is always the same.