# Impedance of individual component in complex AC circuit

Tags: capacitor, inductor, bridge, alternator

In a AC circuit with just a capacitor or inductor, reactance is the impedance of the component, and in a non-complex RLC circuit you can just find the total impedance with vector addition (Ztot = sqrt(R^2 + (Xl - Xc)^2), but in a complex ac circuit how do you find the impedance of a single component?

Say i want to find the impedance of components C2, C3, L2 and L3 in the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVyK6M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Does the resistance of an individual resistor change if it's in a network in a DC circuit?  No.  
Why do you think the impedance of a reactive component changes because it's in a network?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the impedance of each of those, or you want to know the impedance of *that part* of the circuit comprising those?  If the latter, then see @theproton's answer.

Comment: @TimWescott, i meant the former. Every complex AC circuit i've looked at, is structured so that a capacitor or inductor always comes paired in series or parallel with a resistor, and then the impedance is calculated in segments. But as The Photon says, i must find the equivalent impedance of all 5 components.

Comment: The individual impedances are just a function of the component value and the frequency. I.e., a 1F cap at one Hz always has a capacitive impedance of one, regardless of what it's connected to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i want to find the impedance of components C2, C3, L2 and L3 in the circuit below.

These 4 elements can't be combined to find an equivalent impedance because of the presence of R2.

If you want to find the equivalent impedance of all 5 elements, including R2, you will just do the same math you would if they were all resistors, but use their complex impedance values instead of real-valued resistances.

This particular subcircuit can't be solved using just parallel and series combinations, so you'll need to either use more complex combinations like the wye-delta transform or just use KVL or KCL to form equations and solve the circuit.

Comment: You can use my general answer to solving a circuit, given here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/412039/interpretation-of-time-domain-simulation-output/412070#412070 and the s domain transfers of each component. e.g. 1/sC and sL for capacitors and inductors.  Replace s with j*2*pi*f to get the complex frequency response.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that reactance and impedance are not the same thing. The reactance is a value that describes the relationship between the **magnitude** of the voltage across a component and the **magnitude** of the current through the component. The impedance includes this information but also describes the **phase** relationship between the voltage and current. Impedance is typically given as a complex number in rectangular form (\$A + \mathrm{j}B\$) or in polar form (\$C\angle\phi\$). When voltages and currents are expressed this way we call them **phasors**. Note that electrical engineers use 'j' instead of 'i' to represent \$\sqrt{-1}\$.

To find the impedance of inductors and capacitors you must first know the frequency at which they are operating. Then

$$ Z_C = \frac{-\mathrm{j}}{2\pi f} = 2 \pi f C \angle-90$$
and
$$ Z_L = \mathrm{j} 2 \pi f L = 2\pi f L \angle 90$$
The angles are in degrees and the units of impedance are ohms.

Impedances in series or parallel combine just like resistors, except that you must use complex arithmetic.

Comment: I can add to Elliot's answer by adding that the impedance of the component is directly proportional to the frequency of the current flowing through it and the voltage across it. Just read the value of the component and use the equations he has provided to get their individual impedances.

Comment: @JasonMorgan No, impedance is **not** proportional to frequency; a capacitor's impedance goes down as frequency goes up. No, the impedance is **not** proportional to the voltage across it...impedance is independent of applied voltage.

Comment: With respect.  I did not say the voltage, I said the *frequency* of the voltage.